# Monitor changes in table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have 3 Html `table`. the first has a `div` inside a `td` in the table and the others are empty. I try to monitor\track when dragging div from one table to another. I've tried to it with

`$("td").change(function(){});`

but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to track\monitor.. when dragging div from one table to another ?

Comment: The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements. http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can visit the documentation on jquery at this page:

[Jquery Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events)

If you click on view source you can find the Events that you can use to monitor the drag.
Here a code sample copied from it, make attention to drag: callback function:

```
$(function() {
    var $start_counter = $( "#event-start" ),
        $drag_counter = $( "#event-drag" ),
        $stop_counter = $( "#event-stop" ),
        counts = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        start: function() {
            counts[ 0 ]++;
            updateCounterStatus( $start_counter, counts[ 0 ] );
        },
        drag: function() {
            counts[ 1 ]++;
            updateCounterStatus( $drag_counter, counts[ 1 ] );
        },
        stop: function() {
            counts[ 2 ]++;
            updateCounterStatus( $stop_counter, counts[ 2 ] );
        }
    });
...
});
```